# Where do I post my question?

Tags: support, asking-questions, site-recommendation

I have a question about windows apps. I have posted it on **[windowsphone.SE](https://windowsphone.stackexchange.com/questions/2991/if-i-develop-a-html-game-or-an-app-for-windows-pc-will-it-work-on-windows-phones)**

But it is put on hold and suggesting to ask on Stack Overflow. My question was:

> "I am developing an html5 app for windows 8 desktop using js and html
>   so my question is can I use the same app on PC, phones and tablets? "

I think this is not suitable for Stack Overflow Q&A format. Where should I post this?

Comment: Can you edit in a link to the question? (I poked around and found it; I can see why you might be concerned)

Comment: @DennisMeng done :)

Comment: post at http://stackoverflow.com/

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Unfortunately, I think your question as-is will be off-topic on any of the Stack Exchange Network sites as, *"Too Broad"*.

There are dozens of tablets, browsers, and phones out there, and each has their own quirks.

Furthermore, we don't have any details on what aspects of HTML5 or Javascript you are using for the game, which means that even if we had perfect knowledge of the quirks of each platform, we wouldn't be able to know whether or not those quirks would affect your application.

Taking a look at [the Wikipedia Entry](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTML5_in_mobile_devices#HTML5_capabilities_in_top_mobile_devices) will show you that there are some parts of HTML5 which will be supported regardless, and some that won't.

If you already have an application, you can test it.

If you don't have an application, you may want to do some research yourself to see what is and isn't supported, and if there is a specific aspect of HTML5 you want to use but are concerned about whether it is supported on another device (or if support can be kludged together), then asking that specific question will get you much better answers.